# LWC - Is it possible to get the host template attributes?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm hoping to get the host template attributes, but `this.template.host` is null.

e.g.  something like:

```
connectedCallback() {
    console.log(this.template.host.getAttribute('aria-describedby'));
}
```

In the rendered markup in the browser, my LWC looks like:

```
<c-my-lwc aria-describedby='a-value'>
    [additional html content]
</c-my-lwc>
```

I'm hoping the console.log could output 'a-value'.

NOTE: this is a bit of an XY problem, but I don't see any other way of solving my problem.

I was looking at this question: [Can an LWC component get its own name?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/326166/can-an-lwc-component-get-its-own-name)

In this question, the answer refers to getting `this.template.host.localName`, but given `this.template.host` is null, I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was simpler than I thought.

You just need to use `this.getAttribute('aria-describedby')`.

e.g.

```
connectedCallback() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('aria-describedby'));
}
```